# Implications of concatenating EEG signals

Tags: biomedical-engineering, signal

I am wondering about the mathematical implications of concatenating very small windows from different trials.  All of the trials are the same size, and are for the same period of time after a stimuli.

In other words, let's say my data has 3 channels, 6 trials, and 10 data points per trial ( size of data [3x10x6]).  What I want to build is a new data set with the same 3 channels, but with concatenating the windows of 2 datapoints for all of the trials, and then repeating this for the all of the possible number of windows.  In this example it would be 5 windows (size of new data [3x12x5]).

I assume that any frequency analysis will be pointless due to dramatic changes in the signal, but what other implications to the data should I be concerned about? Would it still be reasonable to remove trending or denormalize this new data?

Comment: What is the purpose of building this new synthetic data set?

Comment: Is to build a dataset that have more information for a very small period in time. Another option could be upsampling but it won't due for the type of analysis that I am doing.

Comment: Any Ideas on this topic?

Comment: Best to wait a while - this is a new site, and there are not many biomedical engineers here yet.

Comment: With so few data points per trial, how could you be sure the timeframe matches up and avoid aliasing? From a signal processing standpoint this doesn't sound like a reasonable concatenation for any sort of continuous analysis.